# Using Ext Gwt (gxt) with gwt

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have gone through the tutorial present on the sencha site for using Gxt. Following is the link where i found the tutorial-
http://www.sencha.com/blog/setting-up-your-first-ext-gwt-project-in-eclipse/
I have done exactly as what they have said over there. I would like to know whether I can use the Gxt 2.2.5 with Gwt 2.4. 
If any one who has used Ext Gwt, then please help me out..

I am using Gwt-2.0.4 and ext-gwt is gxt-2.0.1.jar.

Following error is show when I run the web app-
16:51:01.676 [ERROR] [projsecond] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/workspace/wrk/ProjSecond/war/WEB-INF/lib/gxt-2.0.1.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/Component.java'
[ERROR] [projsecond] - Line 1417: Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Gxt 2.2.5 with GWT 2.4 but you must use gxt-2.2.5-gwt22.jar file instead of gxt-2.2.5-gwt2.jar (they are included in GXT archive file). Since GWT 2.0.x - 2.1.x differs in API comparing GWT 2.2.x you must use specially compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem, initially i was using gxt-2.2.5-gwt22 after replacing with gxt-2.2.5-gwt17 it is working fine now.